# SoundPool.stop() causes click/pop?

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am building a music app that play notes of various lengths by playing and then stopping a long audio sample.

```
int streamId = soundPool.play(soundIds[i], 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
soundPool.stop(streamId);
```

On my HTC Droid Incredible running 2.3.4 it works very nicely.  However on my brand new Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2 it makes a loud click as it cuts the samples short (I'd imagine stopping on a non-zero crossing on the audio waveform).

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've checked other apps and the same thing happens on the Galaxy Nexus - clicks and pops.  Working fine on emulator.  Could this be an issue with the model or this particular phone?  Or just 4.2.2

Comment: If your sample if fixed length -- I.e., you always play the same sample length, modify the sample by fading the waveform just before that time.

Comment: @GaryWalker - thanks but it can be any number of different lengths. I've updated my question